# Como transformar um caractere em inteiro em C?

Tags: c, string

Como transformar um caractere em inteiro?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
 char N[11];
 int i;
 scanf("%s",N);
 int cont = strlen(N);

 for(i=0; i<cont; i++)
    { 
     int valor = atoi(N[i]); // Só serve para um conjunto de caracteres
     if (valor >= 9)
        printf("%d",valor-9);
     else
         printf("%c",N[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

 return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings em C, implementadas como array de char, na verdade não são "texto" - são apenas sequências de números de 1 byte (o tipo 'char'). O que faz com que esses números sejam interpretados como texto são só as funções da bibioteca padrão - atoi, printf, strlen, etc... todas esperam um ponteiro de char - um endereço de memória, a partir do qual percorrerão o byte naquele endereço e nos endereços seguintes, interpretando esses bytes como caracteres, até chegar a um byte com valor "0".

Pra ficar claro, um element "char" em C é um número, entre -128 e +127 - que "cabe" em um único byte. A sintaxe da linguagem permite que o valor desse número seja escrito de forma numérica, ou como um caractere, entre aspas-simples (nesse caso, o elemento entre as aspas simples deve ser parte da tabela ASCII, ou usando uma escape sequence tal como '\n', '\xff', etc...). Também, se você estiver trabalhando com valores numéricos de bytes, em geral vale mais a pena trabalhar com o tipo `unsigned char`, que comporta números entre 0 e 255.

Em outras palavras:

```
... 
char a = '0';
printf('%d', (int) a); 
...
```

Vai imprimir o código do caracter '0',que é 48. Enquanto que:

```
... 
char a = '0';
printf('%c', a); 
...
```

vai imprimir o caractére '0', como está: a diferença não está no valor contido na variável 'a', mas sim, em como o `printf` vai usar esse valor - e esse uso é definido pela formatação de string.  O uso do cast `(int)` no primeiro exemplo é só para garantir que o compilador vai colocar o valor de 'a' usando o tamanho do inteiro (em geral 4 bytes) na pilha - senão o '%d" do printf poderia consumir 4 bytes onde haveriam apenas 1 byte - o 'a' passado como (char)  e causar um "Stackunderflow"  - vulgo, estouro de pilha.

Então, no seu código, o problema maior é você chamar o `atoi`, que espera um endereço de memória para uma sequeência de char, que ele vai interpretar como texto, e você passa ao invés disso um único número . Nesse caso, o compilador vai emitir um warning, mas por padrão, vai gerar o código, tratando o seu caractére, um número entre -128 até 127, como um endereço de memória. Ao tentar ler esse "endereço de memória", o código dentro da função atoi não vai ser autorizado pelo sistema operacional, já que esses endereços não fazem parte da parte da memória com dados endereçaveis pelo seu programa, e acontece uma violação de acesso, que é reportada pelo sistema operacinal como um "Segmentation Fault".

## Por fim, respondendo olhando seu código:

Se você simplesmente subtrair o código do caractere '0' de cada caractere da sequência entrada como string, vai ter o valor numérico do dígito:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
 char N[100];  // não tem por que usar um valor pequeno aqui (veja texto abaixo) (*)

 int i;
 scanf("%s",N);
 int cont = strlen(N);

 for(i=0; i<cont; i++)
    { 
     int valor = N(i) - '0'; // Subtrai o valor do código de '0' (48) do carácter digitado;
     if (valor >= 0 && valor > 9)
        {
         printf("Dígito %d \n", valor);
        }
     else
        {
         printf("Caráctere %c \n",N[i]);
        }
    }

 return (0);
}
```

(*) Sobre o 100 em vez de 11 para o array: se o usuário digitar alguns caracteres a mais isso causa um bufferoverflow e resultados imprevisíveis.
N a verdade, 'scanf' deve ser evitado como um todo em código de produção - vide:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar um [cast](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/footnotes/cast.html), exemplo:

```
char c='a';
printf("%d", (int) c);
```

[tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm)

Para converter o caracter '0' -> 0, '1' -> 1, etc

```
char c = '5';
int i = c - '0';
```

Comment: Normalmente sim, e pode sinalizar também, assim outras pessoas fecham, até que você ganhe o privilégio de votar ou até de fechar sozinho mais pra frente.