# Erro em função para trocar caracteres

Tags: c

Tenho que criar uma função para fazer a troca de algum carácter.
O exercício é este:
**1. Construa uma função que receba uma mensagem, seu tamanho e um
caracter e retire todas as ocorrências desse caracter na mensagem
colocando * em seu lugar. A função deve retornar o total de caracteres
retirados.**

E eu fiz o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
void filtro(char msg[500] ,int tamanho, char c){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
    char mensagem[500];
    strcpy(mensagem,msg);
    int i,r=0;
    for (i=0; i<tamanho; i++){
        if(mensagem[i]==c){
            r++;
            mensagem[i] = "*";
        }
    }
    printf("\nMensagem modificada: \n %s", mensagem);
    printf("\nCaracteres retirados: %d", r);
}
void main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
    char msg[500], c;
    printf("Escreva uma mensagem de até 500 caracteres\n");
    gets(msg);
    printf("Informe o caracter a ser removido: ");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    filtro(msg, strlen(msg), c);
}
```

Porém recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:
***[Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast***

Ele até detecta os letras e faz uma troca. Mas ao invés de colocar o '*' ele põe o seguinte caracter: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em C, uma string é fundamentalmente diferente de um único carácter. Strigns são apenas um endereço de memoria que contém uma sequência de caractéres terminados com um byte "0" -no códiog acima, justamente no momento de inserir o novo caractere, o "*", no lugar desejado, você usa a notalção de string - aspas duplas - em vez do valor do `*`, o compilador insere na sua string o byte mais baixo do endereço de memória da string contendo `"*"`;

É só trocar sua linha de inserção para:

```
        mensagem[i] = '*';
```

Em vez de usar as aspas duplas - com essa sintaxe, o código ASCII do valor entre aspas-simples é usado como um único byte que é inserido naquela posição.

Por coincidência, eu escrevi bastante sobre esse funcionamento das strings em C em outra resposta esses dias - vale dar uma olhada lá: [Como transformar um caractere em inteiro em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/323118/como-transformar-um-caractere-em-inteiro-em-c/323151#323151)

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado pela solução e pela ótima explicação!